# Double hop IIS to SQL Server authentication works locally, doesn't work remotely

Tags: sql-server, iis, webforms, kerberos, windows-authentication

A question about double hop authentication browser -> IIS (ASP.NET WebForms app) -> SQL Server.

I have a WebForms website with Web.config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
          ...some DevExpress settings here...
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnStringName" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=0" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
        ...
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        ...
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="110" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <pages validateRequest="true" clientIDMode="Predictable">
        ...
        </pages>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"></sessionState>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
          <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="Default.aspx" />
          </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        ...
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      ...
    </configuration>
```

I need it to work like this: when any user in domain opens site in browser, ASP.NET Web Forms application runs under his Windows credential. Then the same credential must be used to authenticate database calls made by ASP.NET app using SqlConnection class.
For clarity: SQL Server is configured for using Windows authentication. Users that must have access to app and DB are included in a specific AD group. That group is listed in DB's Security - Logins list with data_reader, data_writer permissions (and also they can execute stored procs).

The most interesting is how it *really* works:
#1. When I open browser on the server that IIS is on, type http://localhost:port/ - it works as expected.
#2. When I open browser on my PC, type http://server-name:port/ - it catches SqlConnection opening error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

In both cases, Context.User.Identity.Name and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name are correct.

Why do these two scenarios give different results? How to make #2 work like #1?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a double-hop authentication scenario you must enable [Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview#:%7E:text=Kerberos%20constrained%20delegation%20was%20introduced%20in%20Windows%20Server,can%20act%20on%20the%20behalf%20of%20a%20user.).  See eg  [Setting up Kerberos Authentication for a Website in IIS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/ba-p/347882).

Comment: Second link is dead

Comment: Works for me: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/ba-p/347882

Comment: Hum looks like it works in Edge not Firefox, wonder why

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Some steps in that instruction relate to SPN. If I understand correctly, SPN is needed only to give access to the site by specific hostname instead of servername:port. So I assume, SPN steps may be skipped altogether if I only want it to work by servername:port address. Is it correct?

Comment: Kerberos authentication requires the service account running the service to have a SPN registered.  Without an SPN authentication will fall back to NTLM, which can't do delegation.